# Flash CS4 vs Flash CS5 Actionscript - Should I upgrade?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript, flash-cs4, flash-cs5

From the perspective of coding, what are the major improvements from Flash CS4 to Flash CS5?

Comment: From the perspective of coding, you generally don't code much in the IDE; although the biggest improvement is the deeper integration with Flash Builder.

Comment: Plenty of people code in the IDE. :P

Comment: for folks who don't code using the built-in IDE, please add your pros/cons to your preferred IDE to this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3165466/which-flash-actionscript-ide-to-use-if-one-should-be-used-at-all

Comment: also... I'm especially looking for answers by folks who are currently using CS5 in their regular repertoire (and who have also used CS4, back in its heyday)

Comment: Thats why I love FlashDevelop, it's free!

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the list of new features, there a couple of handy ones for coding:

- Improved Actionscript Editor - you
  can get autocomplete for custom
  classes, similar to Flex/Flash
  Builder

[image: actionscript editor]

- Flash IDE - Flex/Flash Builder round
  tripping:

[image: flash-flex integration]

Don't know how handy the Code Snippets is, but I there is a [CS4 Panel available](http://theflashblog.com/?p=771).
I think [Julian Dolce](http://deleteaso.com/) showcased some round tripping between Flash IDE Flex/Flash Builder
using Ant at [FOTB](http://www.flashonthebeach.com/) '09, but don't know the url.
You might find the mobile profiles handy or the TLF integration as well. More [features here](http://www.adobe.com/products/flash/whatsnew/?promoid=FDTEG).

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to get the CS5 trial and give it a try. If you are mostly working with AS3 code then the upgrade could be better. I was using flash-builder( on as3) + cs4 (flash timeline) but the workflow is not so smooth as for Flex apps.