# Flash Developer IDE

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex

I was wondering which IDE choice you flash developer use to write the code....I use Flex Builder for my AS3 only project so the code below will display nicely with coloring keywords. I wanted to know if there are better choices there...Also, does flash developer do the AS3 programming only? Do they do graphic design at all?

Thanks for the reply...

Comment: sorry, but what's that snippet for?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1385169/best-ide-for-actionscript-3-coding or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3165466/which-flash-actionscript-ide-to-use-if-one-should-be-used-at-all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I really suggest you to use FlashDevelop as your default IDE.

This program is a lot lighter than Flash Builder (which is built on Eclipse).

If FlashDevelop is properly set up (a lot more simple than it seems), you can develop Flash-based applications completely free!

A useful shortcut is available too in FlashDevelop to compile your project in Flash IDE. Simple as [CTRL ENTER].

---

About your question about being a Flash developer and doing only programming, the answer is simple.
**It's up to you.**

I am presently working as a Flash AS3 programmer for a video game developer… and I am quite good at graphic design!

As I am working on a big project, I do not design at all because artists are hired to do this job specifically. But in another hand, if you're working in a small studio or if you are a student/hobbyist, you have more chances to draw/code.

Programmers do not design because normally they are not good at it.
But it doesn't mean that you cannot do it.

<sub>And yeah, we are using FlashDevelop at work!</sub>

Comment: One thing to consider is that FlashDevelop is windows only, which is a significant drawback for those of us who are more graphic design oriented and love our macs.  :)

Comment: In my opinion, if you begin to do serious programming for Flash (or for any other language), using Windows is a must.
Any recent Mac (Intel ones) can run Windows on Boot Camp, so there is no excuses not using FlashDevelop.
And I do love my iMac :)

Comment: Flash Builder also has ctrl enter - and F5 and other shortcuts to compile... Also, does FlashDevelop still offer a free version?

Comment: FlashDevelop is open source. So it will always be free!

Comment: @ascott Just curious, why do you feel Windows is a must for serious Flash development?  That hasn't been my experience, but now you've got me wondering what I've been missing...

Comment: @WadeMuller Well, first, for Flash Develop. This tool has been a revelation for me. Secondly, from my overall experience, I think Windows is ahead to Mac in Flash developement because Flash Player works better on Windows (faster on intensive process) and more user-friendly (eg. if you use SVN versionning)

Answer (score 1):

If by graphic design, you mean if it does something like Windows Form Support... Adobe Flash Builder comes with MXML support, which lets you easily layout common form elements/components.  There is both a source and design mode - the latter lets you WYSIWYG place the form elements.

Comment: Flash Builder is good. I like its IntelliSence - `ctrl-space` shortcut to autocode. Flash Builder lets you combine both .as with .mxml (flex layout). Or, you can just write your actionscript in mxml cdata

Comment: That's what I thought....using Flash CS to write AS is pain in the butt..Have you use FlashDevelop?

Comment: Yes - FlashDevelop was hard to set up - not enough documentation, so I gave up on it. Flash Builder comes with lots of documentation - Adobe even offers a Flex in a Week training video for free online http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/videotraining

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using a combination of Flash (for your graphics, if that's what you are used to) and Flash Builder (for coding happiness).  Here's a decent article on integrating the two tools into your workflow:

http://www.communitymx.com/content/article.cfm?cid=A2D85

Yes, Flash Builder can do some crude WYSIWYG for UI layout and some CSS, but it's really no good for doing graphic work, just like Flash is no good for coding.  You can also look into Adobe Catalyst, which is a new tool that tries to somewhat bridge the gap.