# Flash vs other methods, and, quick and easy

Tags: silverlight, flash, html

I have a question about Flash. I am writing my first browser game, and I am trying to decide on a technology. 
I have a few requirements:

- I don't want to have to pay to write code and a not-complete-crap free IDE would also be good.
- I want most (or > 70%) of "normal" computer users to have it installed, so, Unity's pretty much out.
- I don't really need performance too much
- I need 2D, not 3D
- Needs to be able to communicate with the server, and no extra downloads required.
- Preferably works with the Facebook platform, but, this isn't a requirment.

Now, I would go with Flash as it fills all of my requirements, but, to my understanding, I need to pay for CS5 to get coding with Flash. Is an alternative around this possible?

Are there any other alternatives I'm missing?

Comment: One alternative when targetting Flash Player is haXe (http://www.haxe.org). I have been using it for 4 years now and it has been a darling :) You **will** have to do things differently than with CS5 though - haXe is a language and a compiler, it does not include an IDE which lets you compile animations and effects the way CS5 does, but you still get a lot of freedom as to how you want to import your multimedia assets in haXe (there is SamHaxe for instance.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add onto what ColinE mentioned, FlashDevelop also provides you the ability to download and install the Flex SDK. However, if FlashDevelop as an IDE doesn't work for you, you can also download the [Flex SDK](http://www.adobe.com/cfusion/entitlement/index.cfm?e=flexsdk) yourself.

This is essentially the same thing that's included with Adobe's Flash Builder application, which is basically built on top of Eclipse. This should at least give you a start on creating things in Flash, though you'll be limited to ActionScript 3. I'd suggest sticking with AS3 as it provides a lot of power compared to AS2.

If you do choose to use the Flex SDK, I'll give you a bit of knowledge I've gained since I started using it for developing games. This may be a little long-winded but hopefully it'll answer some of the initial starter questions.

You can develop apps/games using the Flex library but this may increase the size of your SWF file. However, it's worth noting that it's not required to use the library. You can use the compiler (mxmlc) provided in the SDK to build against .as files as well.

From here, there's a few gotchas that might creep in when it comes to assets. Flex provides you the ability to [embed assets](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf60546-7ff2.html) within your class files. Out of the box, it allows for the embedding of a handful of formats, most notably PNG, TTF, XML and SWF. There's a lot that you'll be able to do with Flex from a code standpoint but it's not very pretty for creating the assets themselves. Primarily, I use the Flash IDE only for cases where a project requires a SWF asset, however, most of my projects tend to use PNG.

When using an embedded SWF asset, you may come across an issue where any code that's included in the asset, such as any hover or animation logic as ActionScript, gets stripped out of the copy embedded in the resulting project's SWF. A workaround for this is forcing the mimetype to "application/octet-stream" and using a Loader object's loadBytes() method.

Finally, you should be able to make some sort of progress provided you have some sort of ActionScript knowledge. There are plenty of resources out there but be aware that a fair amount of them still use AS2. The knowledge can be applied with some modifications but may require some extra legwork to implement. The language is fairly easy to work with.

With all that, I wish you luck. Flash gets a lot of flack these days but even with HTML5 nearing final, there's still a lot of features that it will never be able to touch without leveraging Flash in some way.

Comment: Flex itself does not have an IDE. That's what Flash Builder or FlashDevelop can help with. My personal preference is FlashDevelop as it's freely available and offers support for more than just Flash. As for the HTML5 code, it may not take much effort to move the code between JavaScript & ActionScript as they share a basis in ECMAScript.

Answer (score 1):

Flash, Silervlight or HTML5 will tick pretty much all of those boxes for you, however Silverlight is only installed on ~65% of computers at the moment.

HTML5 can be tough to develop with, so perhaps Flash is your best bet. See the following question which discusses Flash IDEs:

[Flash Developer IDE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3463624/flash-developer-ide)

[FlashDevelop](http://www.flashdevelop.org/wikidocs/index.php?title=Main_Page) is a free development environment for Flash.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your question is about which type of development you should use to get this game going, but I would also urge you to consider the future of each of these software sets, and choose based on what you would like more experience in.

Flash has been holding it's ground pretty well, but I've seen it less and less on major sites these days, and I believe HTML 5 is taking pretty good stabs at it. Even Pandora doesn't use flash anymore, and that was a pretty well designed little flash app (they still use AIR for Pandora One, but not their main site). Instead, like many other websites, it's using HTML and JavaScript.

So, while flash is slowly losing ground to HTML and JavaScript, where does Silverlight stand? Microsoft is still pushing their Silverlight technology, and based on Microsoft's support scheme, they'll still be using it for the next few years at least. At the same time, it's based on the .NET framework, so you'll be gaining some valuable WPF and .NET skills by using Silverlight.

There is no right or wrong decision here, it's really just based on which technology you see yourself using *past* this product, and which technology you want to learn.

I'd give it a shot in Silverlight, myself, but that's simply because I dislike flash, and there's already too many HTML and JavaScript developers.

edit:

Silverlight is a relatively small 30 second install. I generally hate installing new plugins, but Silverlight is relatively painless, imo.

Comment: As a side note, Pandora still use Flash for the actual streaming of music, at least in browsers that doesn't support AAC MP4 audio (Firefox, Chrome, Opera). http://www.readwriteweb.com/archives/pandora_redesign_html5_removes_listening_cap.php